# Insert/Delete/Update with two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with identical records, if dbo.tranx_tbl has new record it will be automatically inserted to dbo.master_tbl same goes to delete once the record is deleted from one table it would be deleted also from the other table and so with the update if one of the records has changed its price it will be changed to the other table as well. I don't know what approach shall I use but the approach I have is some kind a risky and it affects the performance especially dealing with thousands of records. Here's my approach I put a scheduler in SQL Server Agent every hour the record will be deleted from dbo.master_tbl as soon as the records are deleted it performs INSERT INTO from dbo.tranx_tbl. Any suggestions? By the way, Trigger is supposed to be the best approach here but it doesn't work in Linked Server.

```
DELETE
FROM
dbo.master_tbl

INSERT INTO dbo.master_tbl
SELECT*
FROM
dbo.tranx_tbl
```

Comment: I assume the inserts/updates/deletes are coming from an application of some sort. Can both tables be changed by the application, or is one supposed to just be a mirror of the other? Just guessing from the names, but it appears that tranx_tbl is the active one, and master_tbl is the mirrored copy.

Comment: Re: "is one supposed to just be a mirror of the other" Yes. Whatever the record in t1 it would be identical to t2. The insert/update/delete execution of the t1 will be coming from the application, t2 however; will be just an independent table but whatever changes in t1 it should be happened to t2 as well.

Comment: @ThirdyLeon: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Re: "but it appears that tranx_tbl is the active one, and master_tbl is the mirrored copy." Seemingly, yes. The application has no interaction with master_tbl though, only tranx_tbl has.

Comment: @GMB, here's the thing tranx_tbl is owned by SQL Server and master_tbl is owned by oracle tried to push the data from tanx_tbl to master_tbl using trigger but there's a limitation with linked server...I thought it would be better to delete the master_tbl and insert all the records from tranx_tbl every hour so that it will be refreshed should there be any new records or any update/delete from the tranx_tbl. Any recommendations to auto update without using bulk delete/insert since trigger is not working?